# Creating a graph with multiple titles and subtitle axis in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I would like to customize my plotly graph to have the yaxis displaying multiple statuses(titles) with their multiple priorities(subtitles).

Below is an example of the outcome.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2UeE.png)

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can do that. Check [this](https://plot.ly/python/axes/#subcategory-axes) link from plotly docs